# Is there any way to post updates in a business location using Google's business API?

Tags: google-api, google-business-profile-api, google-business

As the title says, I'm trying to find a way to post these updates (see picture below) using google's API, I can't find anything about it. I have checked Google's business [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest) and most of it's endpoints are deprecated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the page there is a deprecation schedule: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/sunset-dates

There you can find the new API-Endpoint. I'm also looking for a solution to update opening hours, but it's not that easy to find any information. Even bing is better documented.

Comment: I did email Google about this they did not answer my question, they told me that I  do not have a business account myself which makes it even worse.